# JQuery Autocomplete issue with .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm having a problem using autocomplete in conjunction with other javascript libraries that I need in my project.

When I run this simple example it works fine in the first time. It shows the autocomplete window perfectly, but if I try to change the word I'm typing it generates this error in Chrome:

Uncaught ReferenceError: pos is not defined on the file jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js:2495

This is the code:

```
$(function () {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $("#txtPesquisar").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

and I lead all these javascripts in my master page for my project.

I don't know why I get this error.

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>      
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Utils.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>        

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")%>" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/JuridicOffice.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<%--<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>"  type="text/javascript" ></script>             
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") %>"  type="text/javascript" ></script>--%>

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Uploadify/swfobject.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>     

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jgcharts.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Mascara.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.color.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I red something here in the forum it could be a postback functions but I don't know how to figure it out.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

did you notice? the file vsdoc it's a little bit older than jQuery version, even you should remove the vsdoc.js from the runtime version.

if open the vsdoc you can find with this note.

```
 /*
 * This file has been commented to support Visual Studio Intellisense.
 * You should not use this file at runtime inside the browser--it is only
 * intended to be used only for design-time IntelliSense.  Please use the
 * standard jQuery library for all production use.
 *
 * Comment version: 1.4.4a
 */
```